# Populate combobox from listbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have combobox in one form1 and listbox in form2. The listbox items is filled by xml data. I need to show the listbox items in the combobox from form2 to form1 and also update the combobox if any changes made in the form2 listbox. How to do it?   this is what i did in the form2 to add the items from xml to listbox..

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
if (File.Exists(path_of_xml))
{
    doc.Load(path_of_xml);
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    foreach (XmlNode node in doc.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.Name == "DEVICES")
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node_of_node in node.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node_of_node.Name == "Device")
                {
                    string name = node_of_node["DeviceName"].InnerText;
                    string ip = node_of_node["IPAddress"].InnerText;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(name + "-" + ip);                                
                }
            }
        }
    }
}           `
```

Comment: Pls post whatever code you've tried so far

Comment: What changes do you need to reflect in the combobox ?

Comment: The same items i need to show to the combobox in the form1..@  o_weisman

Comment: That's not a change. That's simply populating both controls with the same list.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the .NET ListBox does not have any events that are fired when the item collection of the ListBox changes (add, remove). So the easiest way would be to implement your own (basic concept):

```
public class Form2: Form
{
    public event EventHandler<ItemChangedEventArgs> ItemChanged;
    protected virtual void FireItemChanged(object o, Action a)
    {
        var e = ItemChanged;
        e?.Invoke(this, new ItemChangedEventArgs(o, a));
    }
    private void AddItem(object o)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(o);
        FireItemChanged(o, Action.Added);
    }
    private void RemoveItem(object o)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(o);
        FireItemChanged(o, Action.Removed);
    }
}
public class ItemChangedEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public object Item {get; private set;}
    public Action Action {get; private set;}
    public ItemChangedEventArgs(object item, Action action)
    {
        Item = item;
        Action = action;
    }
}
public enum Action
{
    Added,
    Removed
}
```

With this, **do not** use the listBox directly, use the private methods `AddItem` and `RemoveItem` instead. This methods will raise the `ItemChanged` event. That way you can listen to the `ItemChanged` event from Form1 and update the ComboBox items if the listBox items are changed.